# How to change a form end email?

Tags: forms

First I should say that am a beginner with WordPress. I am trying to change the email that a form sends the information to. However, when I go to the "Pages" section and open the "contacts" file I don't see any form details. The only thing I see is the text "Contact us now for free estimate:" and the mobile number (see the image bellow), nothing about the form. Any suggestions on how I can access the details of this form so I can change the email that it sends the data to?

[image]

Comment: look in your theme folder, check the page template in the contact page in admin before that

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page

Comment: @inarilo, I was able to find out how to change it. Thank you for your help! If you wish you can add your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: added :) glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin, check the page template used by the contact page, and look for it in your theme folder. Page templates are applied as described here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page